# Java HTTP POST request vs. CURL

Tags: java, http, post, curl

How to translate the following:

```
curl -X POST -d 'param1=value1&param2=value2' http://url/get_file
```

in Java?

I tried as follows, but this does not work and the request is malformed.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://url/get_file");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", value1));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", value2));
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        instream.close();
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: HttpPost request = new HttpPost(http://url/get_file);
You must use a String with HttpPost.

Comment: Use `HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();` instead of the way you are getting your `HttpClient` instance. It shouldn't matter, but still give it a try. Also, include the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: No stacktrace: the request is sent. However, the result is not the one I expect. With CURL, instead, it works pretty fine. Thus, I would like to know where (and why) my Java code and the CURL request are different.